# Linked list (invalid conversion from 'Node<int>*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|)

Tags: c++, list, templates, exception, singly-linked-list

I want to create Node likes Arraylist in c++. When I create a method get(); it said about the error. I don't understand when I go to find the answer on the internet. Can You Please Help Me Find This Answer?

```cpp
template<typename T>

struct Node{           //Node
    T data;
    Node<T> *next;
    Node(){
       next=NULL;
    }
    Node(T value){
        data=value;
        next=NULL;
    }

};

template<typename T>

class LinkedList{   //class Node 
    public:
        Node<T> *head;
        Node<T> *tail;

        void add(T value){         //method create newnode add to tail
            Node<T> *newNode=new Node<T>(value);
            if (head == NULL){
                head=newNode;
                tail=newNode;
            }
            else {
                tail->next=newNode;
                tail=newNode;
            }
        }
        void PrintAll(string Name){   //method print all node
            Node<T> *current;
            int i=0;
            current=head;
            while (current != NULL ){
                printf("%s[%d]=%d\n",Name.c_str(),i,current->data);
                current=current->next;
                i++;
            }
        }
        T get(int index){      //method show node in parameter 
            Node <T> *current=head;
            int count=0;
            while (current != NULL){
                if ( count == index) return current->next;
                current=current->next;
                count++;
            }
        }

};
```

error: invalid conversion from 'Node*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|

Comment: `T get(int index)` should return a T.  It is not returning anything.

Comment: In the T get(int index)  function, you didn't put any return statement at the end. It should return T

Comment: As @LightYagami mentioned, you have a path in `get` function that doesn't return. This may result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure `Node` should be defined within the class `LinkedList` and be a private member of the class.

The member function `PrintAll` should be declared with the 
qualifier `const` (and the name of the function should start with a lower case letter).

The function `get`  shall throw an exception in case when the list contains less data than the specified index. Otherwise it shall return the value of the data member `data` of the found node.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the list can be defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node *next;

        Node() : data( T() ), next( nullptr )
        {
        }

        Node( const T &value ) : data( value ), next( nullptr )
        {
        }
    };

    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *tail = nullptr;

public:
    void add( const T &value )
    {
        Node *newNode = new Node( value );
        if ( head == nullptr )
        {
            head = tail = newNode;
        }
        else 
        {
            tail = tail->next = newNode;
        }
    }

    void printAll( const std::string &name = "" ) const 
    {
        size_t i = 0;

        for ( auto current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
        {
            std::cout << name << i++ << ": " << current->data << '\n';
        }
    }

    T get( size_t index ) const noexcept( false )
    {
        auto current = head;

        while ( index != 0 && current != nullptr ) 
        {
            current = current->next;
            --index;
        }

        if ( current == nullptr ) throw std::out_of_range( "Too big index" );
        else return current->data;
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> list;

    list.add( 1 );
    list.add( 2 );
    list.add( 3 );

    list.printAll();

    try
    {
        for ( size_t pos = 0; ; ++pos )
        {
            auto value = list.get( pos );

            std::cout << "At position " << pos << " there is stored " << value << '\n';
        }            
    }
    catch ( const std::exception &ex )
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
At position 0 there is stored 1
At position 1 there is stored 2
At position 2 there is stored 3
Too big index
```

Of course you should append the definition of the list with a destructor, copy constructor and the copy assignment operator. In this case you have also explicitly to define the default constructor.

Comment: What does it mean `Node() : data( T() ), next( nullptr )` ? .why not using the same `Node(){
       next=NULL;
    }`@Vlad

Comment: Can you explain more about head=tail=newNode;

Comment: @JackyTeerapat The assignment operator is evaluated right to left. In fact this expression statement head = tail = newNode; is equivalent to these statements tail = newNode; head = tail;

Answer (score 2):

Inside `get()` you're returning a `Node*` instead of `T`, inside the `if` to be precise. 
You should probably do this:

```
    T get(int index){      //method show node in parameter 
        Node <T> *current=head;
        int count=0;
        while (current != NULL){
            if ( count == index) return current->data;
            current=current->next;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

You should also handle the case in which the index is not valid, throwing an exception is ok in these cases.

Comment: Thank you!  .I have 1 questions,what that mean current->next->data

Comment: It returns the value of `data`, the variable inside `Node`. I've also made a mistake it should be `current->data`, I'll fix the answer.